# How would low gravity on Mars be a stress factor on plants?

Tags: mars, gravity, astrobiology, science, plants

As a 12 year old doing a science project for my local science fair I have found that many experiments that try to simulate how the environment would be like on Mars while growing plants always forget to include one factor. That factor is the gravity on Mars (3.721 m/s² on Mars vs. 9.807 m/s² on Earth) would be a HUGE stress factor on plants. I have struggled to find information regarding how this would affect the plant's hormones (maybe auxin flow?). If anyone knows how this would happen (please go into detail) inform me please. Or could someone link sources explaining how this would happen (study websites). I can't find any direct information on Nasa.gov.

Comment: I'm unaware of plant experiments being undertaken on either Mars or the Moon (even lower gravity than Mars), by any nation, including China. [Plants have been grown in low gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plants_in_space), on space stations, such as the ISS.

Comment: @fred, China sprouted some seeds on the moon, but they died from uncontrolled temperature swings so not really useful in answering this https://www.npr.org/2019/01/17/686169520/plant-china-mooned-over-dies-couldnt-cotton-to-lunar-environment

Comment: @GremlinWranger: thanks for the details about China's failed attempt to grow cotton on the Moon.

Comment: more on that: [Why did the Chinese send flies and plants to the far side of the moon?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33618/12102) and [Where is that lunar-grown cotton seed sprout?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33636/12102) and [How does this spinach-growing Mars lander design work?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30020/12102)

Comment: hey @Fred I meant like experiments simulating the martian environment on earth. There have been many off those.

Comment: "...always forget to include one factor." How would they include it on the Earth's surface, even if they remembered?

Comment: @OrganicMarble yeah my bad they can't really include it. I haven't actually looked into it much.